# Ubuntu 22.04.05 blocking IP addresses it shouldn't

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 22.04.05 is blocking IP addresses that I use frequently. Example: I use a webmail site for email. I cannot reach the site on my main machine, yet every other computer on my network can reach the site. Ping returns Host not available.
Another example: I use a web based database for tracking events. Again on my main computer it has started blocking the IP messages.
I have ufw disabled and I don't have a proxy. Where should I look to find what is blocking the address?

Comment: 22.04.5 doesn't exist yet.  It is only up to 22.04.1.   Are you certain that you aren't running 20.04.5?  Have you checked the DNS server on this host vs the other hosts?  One way to tell is to do a `nslookup www.google.com` and check what the Server: and Address: lines are.  Also, is your IP addressing in the same subnet as the rest of your network?

Comment: My mistake on Ubuntu 22.04.1 which I assume is an upgrade from 22.04.05. nslookup on all computers gives the same Server and address lines 127.0.0.53 which is outside my natted subnet.

Comment: Even though ufw is disabled I wonder of some iptables rules linger? Do `sudo iptables -xvnL`. The IP address `127.0.0.53` is local loopback and is okay.

Comment: iptables are empty